# Java Scanner.next is blocked seemingly without reason

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get user inputs in a while:

```
package com.projet.geometrie;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TestGeo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input_reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean retour = false;
        boolean first = true;
        List<Vertex> listePoints = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!retour) {
            System.out.println("Entrez une coordonnée au format : x,y");
            String coord = input_reader.next();
            String[] coordSplit = coord.split(",");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(coordSplit[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(coordSplit[1]);
            if (!first) {
                if (x != listePoints.get(0).getX() && y != listePoints.get(0).getY()) {
                    Vertex nouveauPoint = new Vertex(x, y);
                    listePoints.add(nouveauPoint);
                    if (listePoints.size() > 1) {
                    }
                } else {
                    retour = true;
                }
            } else {
                first = false;
                Vertex nouveauPoint = new Vertex(x, y);
                listePoints.add(nouveauPoint);
            }
        }
        input_reader.close();

        Section test = new Section(listePoints);

        System.out.println("Nombre de sommets : " + listePoints.size());
        System.out.println("Aire du polygone : " + test.getAire());
        System.out.println("Centroide X : " + test.getCoordCentroide().get(0) + " Y : " + test.getCoordCentroide().get(1));

    }
}
```

But at some point, after I enter the input, my code just gets stuck. I write the input, press enter and it just skips a line, as it is no longer reading the input. It mostly happens after 3 iterations, but sometimes it's 2, other times it's 4. In debug mode it just get stuck at trying to read.

Anyone has an idea of what I did wrong?

I'm using jdk 10.0.2, let me know if any other information could be useful, I'm new to java.

*EDIT : Posted the full code with which I'm experiencing the bug. The class Vertex is just a grouping of 2 int and was tested, I know it works. This class is supposed to take coordinates input from the user and add the point to a list of point. If the last point entered is the same as the first one, it stops and show some information about the created polygon.

Comment: Scanner will block until you give it `next`?

Comment: not sure if this is related to your problem or not, but you should not be closing System.in

Comment: also: I think you intended to use nextLine, not next

Comment: Also is this `while` loop within another loop? Do you try to read from `System.in` again later in your code? The code you've posted works fine on my machine

Comment: [mcve] if you want serious help. You're asking about a bug in your code, but not presenting code that unambiguously demonstrates the problem, and so you're getting a lot of guesses. With a decent MCVE post, we could  likely give you a clear explanation and solution quickly.

Comment: Edited the question to include the entire class. Isn't input_reader.close() closing the System.in?

Comment: Please also provide some input to reproduce the problem, and please further explain what you mean by "stuck". Is the program ended, or something else wrong?

Comment: the input is a string with this format [int 1],[int 2]. And by stuck I mean that nothing happens, I enter the input string and the program no longer ask for the next input as expected, nor does it end, as if it was stuck in an infinite loop, but there's no loop (it jams between line 16 an 17, I tried to put a print between thoses lines and it never was executed).

Comment: Use the debugger Luke!

Comment: Did use it. Once I reach the part where I should enter the input nothing happens.

Comment: I don't mind my question being voted down as I'm here to get an answer, not some points. But If by downvoting someone means to say that my question can't be answered for some reason, I would like to know what that reason is.

Comment: If this were my code, I'd use `.nextLine()` with my Scanner object, not `.next()`

Comment: Is the difference between .next() and .nextLine() similar to cin and getline() in c++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work by using .nextInt() and asking the user to enter the x and the y separately (as 2 different inputs). I think it had something to do with the fact that strings were involved in the process, though I'm not sure why it would be problematic. If anyone has an explanation I would be glad to know more even if it's working now.